# Getting selected values of a list box?

Tags: xpages

How do I get the selected items is a list, combobox etc?

I found this bit of code [here](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-selectable-values-of-a-component):

```
/*****
 *** getSelectableValues()
 *** prints all selectable values for a given component, f.e. comboboxes, listboxes etc.
 ***
 *** @params id of component
 *****/

function getSelectableValues( id ) {
   var ComboBox = getComponent( id );
   var ChildrenList:java.util.ListIterator;
   ChildrenList = ComboBox.getChildren().listIterator();
   while (ChildrenList.hasNext()) {
      var Child = ChildrenList.next();

      /*** process computed / multiple values ***/
      if( typeof( Child ) == 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemsEx' ){
         var hlp = Child.getValue();
         for( var i=0; i< hlp.length; i++ ){

            /*** print to server console ***/
            print( hlp[i].getLabel() + "|" + hlp[i].getValue() );
         }
      }

      /*** process single values ***/
      if( typeof( Child ) == 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UISelectItemEx' ){

      /*** print to server console ***/
      print( Child.getItemLabel() + "|" + Child.getItemValue() );
      }
   }
}

/*** get all selectable values for element 'comboBox1' ***/
getSelectableValues( 'comboBox1' );
```

But it seems to get ALL of the items in a list box and not just the selected ones.  Any ideas how to modify it to get just the selected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the selected values with SSJS:

```
getComponent('comboBox1').value
```

If you are working with a list box and multiple selection is enabled, you can use Explode to get an array of strings:

```
@Explode(getComponent('listBox1').value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking the component, ask the data model. For instance, if the list box is bound to:

```
#{someDoc.someItemName}
```

...then you can retrieve the selected values by asking the data source:

```
var selectedValues = someDoc.getValue("someItemName");
```

If the component is instead bound to a scoped variable:

```
#{viewScope.selectedValues}
```

...then just ask that variable:

```
var selectedValues = viewScope.get("selectedValues");
```

Comment: If your box is attached to your data model this is the better approach